# Using tooltip in emberJs

Tags: jquery, ember.js

**Problem**

I want to show a tooltip on click of a link. 
When I click on a link it will open a tooltip on that link.
Here i will add data to form then hit save.
Now i want to save this data using ember data.

I dont understand what should I use to achieve this.

**What I have done**

Till now I am loading all tooltips in a view at the end of body tag.

As the view loaded i do this to init the tooltip

```
//initiate the popup for adding new task as the view loaded
didInsertElement : function(){

    //Ember current object
    var self = this;

    //element we need to attach qtip on to
    var trigger_elm = $("#trigger-add-task");

    //if element is loaded then attach
    if(trigger_elm.length > 0){
        trigger_elm.qtip({
            content : {         
                text : $("#popups #popup-add-task").remove(),
                title: 'Add New Task', 
                button : 'Close'
            },
            style : {
                classes : 'font-lucida qtip-light qtip-bootstrap'
            },
             position: {
                my: 'center left', 
                at: 'center right', 
            },
            show: {
                event: 'click',
                solo: true
            },
            hide: {
                event: 'click',
            },
        })
    }

},
actions : {
    saveTask : function(){
        console.log('Ember running');
    }
},
```

Now everything is working but I dont know how can i add other js functionality in the form loaded in view. Like adding new rows on click. handling a few events. where should i do that

What should I use to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events (called actions in Ember.js) can be handled in a number of different places, depending on what you are trying to do:

- The view or component
- The controller
- The route

In your template, use an {{action}} to specify this:

```
<button {{action 'addRow'}}>Add Row</button>
```

The controller will handle this first, the addRow action is implemented:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    addRow: function() {
      // Do something here
    }
  }
});
```

If you return true from the controller action, the route action (if it exists) will be triggered also. If you want to target the view, change the template like this:

```
<button {{action 'addRow' target='view'}}>Add Row</button>
```

Now, which should you choose?

If you are going to be doing something which doesn't affect the data, and you are changing the DOM only, then target the view. Otherwise, target the controller or route. If you are altering the model, e.g adding a record to the model array, then do this in the controller. If you need to communicate with the server, then do it in the route. There are no hard and fast rules though.